# How to prove that a homogeneous system of linear equations with more unknowns than equations has infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know how to prove the following statement for my upcoming Linear Algebra Exam:

Prove that a homogeneous system of linear equations with more unknowns than equations has infinitely many solutions.

Note: Only elementary proofs are allowed. That is, assume you know nothing about ranks or any properties of matrices.

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Do you know what a "homogeneous system of linear equations" is? Do you know what linear dependence is?

Comment: Are you familiar with Rouché-Capelli theorem? What happens if the rank of a homogeneous system is smaller than the number of unknowns?

Comment: @MeesdeVries Well Obviously. But I want to see how people would prove it here.

Comment: @IntegrationOverlord: this site is a not a place for others to do your homework. you must show some of your own ideas in order to get an answer.

Comment: @symplectomorphic It's not homework. It's for an exam

Comment: A standard method begins by identifying the largest non-vanishing determinant of the coefficient matrix, and then uses expansion rules of determinants to produce a non-trivial solution. Given a non-trivial solution you get infinitely many as scalar multiples. The construction is a bit delicate, but I used to drill my linear algebra students in using it in numerical cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Prove that a homogeneous system of linear equations with more unknowns than equations has infinitely many solutions.

**Notes**

First, a homogeneous system of linear equations is one where each of the constant terms is zero. For example, a homogeneous system of $m$ equations with $n$ variables has the form $$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n = 0$$ $$a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+...+a_{2n}x_n=0$$ $$a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+...+a_{mn}x_n=0$$
All homogeneous systems have at least one solution, where all variables have the value $0$; this is, of course, a trivial solution. Finally, it should be noted that the solution set to $Ax=0$ is the same as the null space of $A$.

**Example**

For a system $$x_1-x_2+3x_3=0$$ $$2x_1+x_2+3x_3=0$$ We can set up the augmented matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3&0\\2&1&3&0\end{bmatrix}$$ This then row-reduces to $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&0\\0&1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ Which gives the equations $$x_1+2x_3=0$$ $$x_2-x_3=0$$ If we say that $t=x_3$, then the solution set is given by $$x=-2t, \quad x_2=t, \quad x_3=t$$ Therefore this system has an infinite number of solutions, one of which is $t=0$ (the trivial solution).

For the proof the same techniques can be used as above but for a general matrix.